# What is the type of this.refs.nav for NavigatorIOS in React Native?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm using NavigatorIOS with `ref="nav"`.  In my callback for `onRightButtonPress`, I'm using this code

`(this.refs["nav"] as any).push({
  component: AddingScene,
  title: "Adding",
});`

I've tried casting `this.refs["nav"]` as many things (NavigatorIOS, NavigationIOS etc.) but can't find a type for it.  Does anyone have a cast that will work in TypeScript here so that we have intellisense on the `refs["nav"]` object?

Comment: You could try passing a [callback](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#the-ref-callback-attribute) to ref instead of a string, TypeScript should correctly infer the type through the callback argument: `ref={elem => ...}` -- this would allow you to inspect the type.

Comment: Update: We're using react-navigation now per the new standard, and a callback in the ref as @JohnWeisz suggested.

      ref={(component) => this._myComponent = component}